# How to check AWS lambda function last used

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How can we check, when was the lambda function in AWS was last used.
I was going the through the lambda function details and was able to find only the last modified entry.
Is the last modified entry same as last used entry?

Comment: Do you refer the last time the function was executed?

Comment: Do we need to check in Cloud Trail?

Answer (score 3):

By last used I assume you are looking for the last invocation of a function.

In the Lambda console you can see this if you go to the `Monitoring` tab -> `Metrics` -> `Invocations`:

[image]

If you don't see anything in the Invocations graph, you can increase the time period for which these metrics are fetched:

[image]

Since these are CloudWatch metrics, you can retrieve this information by going into CloudWatch and searching for the `Invocations` metric for your function. But this is not necessary, the Lambda console displays this conveniently for you.

The last modified entry is probably not what you are looking for. This stores that date and time when the Lambda code was modified last time, not when it was invoked last time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ervin, i will have a look in this the way you have suggested.